# Creating a loop to upload Excel into SQL datanase

Tags: excel, vba

so I have some code below which is supposed to loop through rows and columns and upload the entries into a SQL DB (with Ado). The connection and everything works, I am just struggling to understand why the string isn't being properly constructed. I watched it with Locals open and it seems that strValues gets reset every iteration, which makes it useless.

```
Sub generic_lookup()

 Dim lngRow As Long, lngCol As Long, strSQL As String, strValues As String
   lngRow = Sheets("Upload").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
   lngCol = Sheets("Upload").Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

  strSQL = "INSERT INTO mytable (value1, value2, value3)" & vbNewLine
       For i = 6 To lngRow
            strValues = strValues & "select " & ""
            For X = 1 To lngCol
            strValues = Sheets("Upload").Cells(lngRow, lngCol)
            Next X
            strValues = Left(strValues, Len(strValues)) & vbNewLine
            strValues = strValues & " from dual union all" & vbNewLine
       Next i

       If strValues <> "" Then
           strValues = Left(strValues, Len(strValues) - 11)
           strSQL = strSQL & strValues

            conn.Execute (strSQL)

           strValues = ""
           strSQL = ""
       End If

conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

I am not quite sure how to fix this issue and keep values within strValues. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You need to grab the value out of your cell: `strValues = Sheets("Upload").Cells(lngRow, lngCol).Value`. Otherwise `strValues` stays blank, gets adjusted blank, and then reset to blank.

Comment: Also, I think your `For` loop around `strValues` is structured wrong? `Next X` should probably be just prior to `Next i`.

Comment: How would I go about grabbing the values out of the cell? Watching it in Locals confirms that it indeed gets "select" then adjusts blank as the loop goes on.

Comment: The line I gave you. You just need `.Value` on the end.

Comment: I'll put it in an answer for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are not actually selecting values in your loop.

You need to add `.Value`. Here is the adjusted code:

```
Sub generic_lookup()

Dim lngRow As Long, lngCol As Long, strSQL As String, strValues As String
lngRow = Sheets("Upload").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
lngCol = Sheets("Upload").Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

strSQL = "INSERT INTO mytable (value1, value2, value3)" & vbNewLine
   For i = 6 To lngRow

        strValues = strValues & "select " & ""

        Dim addedAValue As Boolean
        blnAddedAValue = False

        For x = 1 To lngCol

            Dim strCellValue As String
            strCellValue = Sheets("Upload").Cells(lngRow, lngCol).Value

            If Not StrComp(strCellValue, "") Then
                If Not blnAddedAValue Then
                    strValues = strValues & strCellValue
                    blnAddedAValue = True
                Else:
                    strValues = strValues & strCellValue & ", "
                End If
            End If

        Next x

            strValues = Left(strValues, Len(strValues)) & vbNewLine
            strValues = strValues & " from dual union all" & vbNewLine

   Next i

   If strValues <> "" Then
       strValues = Left(strValues, Len(strValues) - 11)
       strSQL = strSQL & strValues

        conn.Execute (strSQL)

       strValues = ""
       strSQL = ""
   End If

conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Of note, you are still over-writing `strValues` several times in your `X` loop - are you sure you mean to do that?

Edit: Code above updated to only add to the existing strValues string. The boolean checks to see whether the next value needs to be added with a comma. Adjust as needed.

Comment: I don't want to overwrite it, which seems to be the issue. I need to retain those values and keep adding it onto strValues each iteration of the loop. My question was worded poorly

Comment: @tokyo_north I adjusted the code above to prevent your over-write issue. I added a boolean flag to help with the formatting of the SQL string for commas, etc. This was a quick edit, so please step through it to make sure it's building the strings properly.